# Tabularx + Multicolumn + numeric columns - Alignment how?

Tags: tabularx, multicolumn

Hopefully this isn't a duplicate post, I was not able to find the appropriate answer at least.
As I am still new to Latex I did a lot of reading here to create my table in bootab style with a descriptive column first (line break, due to long text) and 5 numerical columns for categories.

Problem is, that though I thought to have defined the alignment, the numerical columns don't seem to do as ordered ^^ 
Maybe it's due to the X column type, but i couldn't figure out how to fix it, so far. Also I violated the rule of not using multicol, because I need headers for my categories. The picture shows the results, which are decent I think, but still display this strange alignment of the columns. Would it be easier to just align all columns, except the first, the same way (including the multicols) ?

[image]

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,numbers=noenddot,headinclude
            12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage{microtype}        
\usepackage{marvosym}      
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.85in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.46}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\flushbottom

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table} 
    \begin{spacing}{1.0}
\caption[Tabelle 3.1]
        {"Ubersicht wichtiger Kennzahlen der identischen, indirekt absetzenden Gartenbauhaupterwerbsbetriebe (10 Jahre) mit Spezialisierung Zierpflanzenbau}
\label{Tabelle 3.1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{        % {\hsize}{p{0.1666666\textwidth}*{6}{L}} wenn alle gleich sein sollen
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hsize=2\hsize}X
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
    >{\raggedleft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.8\hsize}X
       % sum=6.0\hsize for 6 columns
 }
    \toprule
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Topfpflanzen} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Schnittblumen}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Jungpflanzen}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Stauden} \\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Nicht-Azerca}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Azerca}&            &             &           \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Anzahl Betriebe}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{690}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{335}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{314}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{12}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{39} \\
     \midrule
Betriebsfl"ache [ha]&     3,42&     6,20&     2,64&     2,84&     3,91\\
FALSCH [m\textsuperscript{2}/AK]& 1.846& 1.502& 2.083&   644&   243\\
Hochglas beheizbar [m\textsuperscript{2}]&11.405& 9.043& 6.778& 9.607& 2.138\\
Hochglas nicht-beheizbar [m\textsuperscript{2}]&   840&   334&   356&    66& 1.448\\
Freiland Zierpflanzen [m\textsuperscript{2}]&14.113&47.706&11.886& 2.500&18.664\\
     \textbf{Kapitalstruktur} \\
Anteil Fremdkapital am Verm"ogen [\%]&    54,19&    42,29&    37,16&    60,00&    33,88\\
Anteil Fremdkapital am Anlageverm"ogen o. Boden [\%]&   135,94&   178,48&    82,17&    93,33&   214,24\\
Kapital je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]&92.555&105.697&99.825&53.828&76.670\\
Maschinen und Fuhrpark je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]&19.818&21.273&16.714&10.326& 5.170\\
     \textbf{Arbeitswirtschaft} \\
Arbeitskr"afte insgesamt [AK]&     7,50&     6,99&     3,75&    16,72&    17,89\\
Anteil Fremd-Arbeitskr"afte an den AK [\%]&    65,82&    67,55&    39,05&    86,92&    88,74\\
Nettoinvestitionen je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]& 1.081& 2.460&-1.430&-2.669&   744\\
     \textbf{Erfolgsgr"o"sen} \\
Gewinn je Familien-AK [\EUR{}/AK]                        &87.673&96.301&36.737&19.645&65.362\\
Anteil Reinertrag am BE [\%]&    -2,65&     7,76&    -5,81&    -5,28&     1,62\\
Bereinigter BE pro EQM [\EUR{}/EQM]&     2,74&     2,29&     1,80&     4,78&     8,72\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{spacing}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: If problem is with `Anzahl Betriebe` row, you could use `\multicolumn{1}{r}{690}`. But if the problem is aligning integers and decimals, you could look a `siunitx` `S` columns.

Comment: thanks! this solved the problem with my alignment. i didn't know of the siunitx package :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really never want to use `X` columns for numeric data (which means you hardly ever want to use `tabularx` for numeric data) `X` columns are all about adjusting *line breaking* within the column and here you only ever want linebreaking in the first column so that should be the only column using `X`,  then for the numeric alignment use a column type designed for that, either `S` column from `siunitx` or `D` column from `dcolumn` pacakges. I used `S` here as you have a mixture of `,` and `.` which is harder to handle with `dcolumn`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,numbers=noenddot,headinclude
            12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage{microtype}        
\usepackage{marvosym}      
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.85in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.46}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\flushbottom

%\usepackage{dcolumn}\newcolumntype{d}{D,,{3.3}}

\usepackage{siunitx}\newcolumntype{d}{S}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table} 
    \begin{spacing}{1.0}
\caption[Tabelle 3.1]
        {"Ubersicht wichtiger Kennzahlen der identischen, indirekt absetzenden Gartenbauhaupterwerbsbetriebe (10 Jahre) mit Spezialisierung Zierpflanzenbau}
\label{Tabelle 3.1}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{        % {\hsize}{p{0.1666666\textwidth}*{6}{L}} wenn alle gleich sein sollen
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X
    *{5}{d}
       % sum=6.0\hsize for 6 columns
 }
    \toprule
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Topfpflanzen} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Schnittblumen}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Jungpflanzen}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Stauden} \\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Nicht-Azerca}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Azerca}&            &             &           \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Anzahl Betriebe}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{690}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{335}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{314}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{12}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{39} \\
     \midrule
Betriebsfl"ache [ha]&     3,42&     6,20&     2,64&     2,84&     3,91\\
FALSCH [m\textsuperscript{2}/AK]& 1.846& 1.502& 2.083&   644&   243\\
Hochglas beheizbar [m\textsuperscript{2}]&11.405& 9.043& 6.778& 9.607& 2.138\\
Hochglas nicht-beheizbar [m\textsuperscript{2}]&   840&   334&   356&    66& 1.448\\
Freiland Zierpflanzen [m\textsuperscript{2}]&14.113&47.706&11.886& 2.500&18.664\\
     \textbf{Kapitalstruktur} \\
Anteil Fremdkapital am Verm"ogen [\%]&    54,19&    42,29&    37,16&    60,00&    33,88\\
Anteil Fremdkapital am Anlageverm"ogen o. Boden [\%]&   135,94&   178,48&    82,17&    93,33&   214,24\\
Kapital je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]&92.555&105.697&99.825&53.828&76.670\\
Maschinen und Fuhrpark je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]&19.818&21.273&16.714&10.326& 5.170\\
     \textbf{Arbeitswirtschaft} \\
Arbeitskr"afte insgesamt [AK]&     7,50&     6,99&     3,75&    16,72&    17,89\\
Anteil Fremd-Arbeitskr"afte an den AK [\%]&    65,82&    67,55&    39,05&    86,92&    88,74\\
Nettoinvestitionen je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]& 1.081& 2.460&-1.430&-2.669&   744\\
     \textbf{Erfolgsgr"o"sen} \\
Gewinn je Familien-AK [\EUR{}/AK]                        &87.673&96.301&36.737&19.645&65.362\\
Anteil Reinertrag am BE [\%]&    -2,65&     7,76&    -5,81&    -5,28&     1,62\\
Bereinigter BE pro EQM [\EUR{}/EQM]&     2,74&     2,29&     1,80&     4,78&     8,72\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{spacing}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's better than yours, but this can be done with `siunitx`

[image]

```
\documentclass[ twoside,openright,titlepage,fleqn,numbers=noenddot,headinclude
            12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage{microtype}        
\usepackage{marvosym}      
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.85in}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9in}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.46}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\flushbottom

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table} 
    \begin{spacing}{1.0}
\caption[Tabelle 3.1]
        {"Ubersicht wichtiger Kennzahlen der identischen, indirekt absetzenden Gartenbauhaupterwerbsbetriebe (10 Jahre) mit Spezialisierung Zierpflanzenbau}
\label{Tabelle 3.1}
    \sisetup{table-number-alignment=center,
        table-figures-decimal = 2,
        output-decimal-marker={,},
        group-separator={.},
        group-minimum-digits=4} 
    \begin{tabular}{p{.25\textwidth}SSSSS}     
    \toprule
                &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Topfpflanzen} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Schnittblumen}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Jungpflanzen}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Stauden} \\
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Nicht-Azerca}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Azerca}&            &             &           \\
    \midrule
\textbf{Anzahl Betriebe}&690&335&314&12&39\\
     \midrule
Betriebsfl"ache [ha]&     3,42&     6,20&     2,64&     2,84&     3,91\\
FALSCH [m\textsuperscript{2}/AK]& 1846& 1502& 2083&   644&   243\\
Hochglas beheizbar [m\textsuperscript{2}]&11405& 9043& 6778& 9607& 2138\\
Hochglas nicht-beheizbar [m\textsuperscript{2}]&   840&   334&   356&    66& 1.448\\
Freiland Zierpflanzen [m\textsuperscript{2}]&14113&47706&11886& 2500&18664\\
     \textbf{Kapitalstruktur} \\
Anteil Fremdkapital am Verm"ogen [\%]&    54,19&    42,29&    37,16&    60,00&    33,88\\
Anteil Fremdkapital am Anlageverm"ogen o. Boden [\%]&   135,94&   178,48&    82,17&    93,33&   214,24\\
Kapital je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]&92555&105697&99825&53828&76670\\
Maschinen und Fuhrpark je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]&19818&21273&16714&10326& 5170\\
     \textbf{Arbeitswirtschaft} \\
Arbeitskr"afte insgesamt [AK]&     7,50&     6,99&     3,75&    16,72&    17,89\\
Anteil Fremd-Arbeitskr"afte an den AK [\%]&    65,82&    67,55&    39,05&    86,92&    88,74\\
Nettoinvestitionen je Arbeitskraft [\EUR{}/AK]& 1081& 2460&-1430&-2669&   744\\
     \textbf{Erfolgsgr"o"sen} \\
Gewinn je Familien-AK [\EUR{}/AK]                        &87673&96301&36737&19645&65362\\
Anteil Reinertrag am BE [\%]&    -2,65&     7,76&    -5,81&    -5,28&     1,62\\
Bereinigter BE pro EQM [\EUR{}/EQM]&     2,74&     2,29&     1,80&     4,78&     8,72\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{spacing}
    \end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! this solved the problem with my alignment. i didn't know of the siunitx package :)